# How to decrease IF statements in this code with array in descending order

Tags: pine-script

I am learning pine-script and now I need to get 40 data (float values) from a array in descending order, but for each value I need the symbol for that value and plot like this:

1 - Bitcoin - 0.2%
2 - ETH - 0.19%
3 - ADA - 0.151%
and so on ...

example:

```
//getting symbols 
f1s = input(type=input.symbol, defval="BINANCE:BTCUSDTPERP", title="symbol 1")
f2s = input(type=input.symbol, defval="BINANCE:ETHUSDTPERP", title="symbol 2")
f3s = input(type=input.symbol, defval="BINANCE:1000SHIBUSDTPERP", title="symbol 3")
f4s = input(type=input.symbol, defval="BINANCE:1000XECUSDTPERP", title="symbol ")
f5s = input(type=input.symbol, defval="BINANCE:1INCHUSDTPERP", title="symbol 5")


//ratios are ascent and descent percentage, the logic is not here
// new array
arr = array.from(ratio1, ratio2, ratio3, ratio4, ratio5) // ...and so on...
array.sort(arr, order.descending)
item1 = array.get(arr, 0)
item2 = array.get(arr, 1)
item3 = array.get(arr, 2)
item4 = array.get(arr, 3)
item5 = array.get(arr, 4)
// ...and so on...

//now I need SEVERAL if's... 
name1 = if item1 == ratio1
    f1s
else if item1 == ratio2
    f2s
else if item1 == ratio3
    f3s
else if item1 == ratio4
    f4s
else if item1 == ratio5
    f5s

name2 = if item2 == ratio1
    f1s
else if item2 == ratio2
    f2s
else if item2 == ratio3
    f3s
else if item2 == ratio4
    f4s
else if item2 == ratio5
    f5s
```

for each symbol, I need to make a 'if' with 39 'else if' arguments... so I would like to know if there is a better way to write this code...

Answer (score 0):

To make it a bit shorter you could use ternaries

```
//now I need SEVERAL if's... 
name1 = if item1 == ratio1
    f1s
else if item1 == ratio2
    f2s
else if item1 == ratio3
    f3s
else if item1 == ratio4
    f4s
else if item1 == ratio5
    f5s
```

Becomes

```
name1 = item1 == ratio1 ? f1s : item1 == ratio2 ? f2s : item1 == ratio3 ? f3s : item1 == ratio4 ? f4s : item1 == ratio5 ? f5s : na
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matrix` function. On first column you can the symbol and on the second column you can set the relevant ratio.

After creating the `matrix` you can then use `matrix.sort()` function. Check the different arguments you can use [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_matrix%7Bdot%7Dsort).

After sorting, the rows will be sorted, but each row will still contain the symbol and the relevant ratio, so you can get the values using `matrix.get()` function.

You can read more about the `matrix` function [here](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/matrices-come-to-pine-script-30693/).